# Corr of one column with all other numeric ones

Tags: python, python-polars

Starting with

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3],
    'b': [4.,2.,6.],
    'c': ['w', 'a', 'r'],
    'd': [4, 1, 1]
})
```

how can I get the correlation between `a` and all other numeric columns?

Equivalent in pandas:

```py
In [30]: (
    ...:     pd.DataFrame({
    ...:         'a': [1,2,3],
    ...:         'b': [4.,2.,6.],
    ...:         'c': ['w', 'a', 'r'],
    ...:         'd': [4, 1, 1]
    ...:     })
    ...:     .corr()
    ...:     .loc['a']
    ...: )
Out[30]:
a    1.000000
b    0.500000
d   -0.866025
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

---

I've tried

```
(
    df.select([pl.col(pl.Int64).cast(pl.Float64), pl.col(pl.Float64)])
    .select(pl.pearson_corr('a', pl.exclude('a')))
)
```

but got

```
DuplicateError: Column with name: 'a' has more than one occurrences
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `DataFrame.pearson_corr` which you could then filter.

```
>>> df.select([
...    pl.col(pl.Int64).cast(pl.Float64), 
...    pl.col(pl.Float64)] 
... ).pearson_corr()   
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ a         ┆ d         ┆ b   │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ 1.0       ┆ -0.866025 ┆ 0.5 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.866025 ┆ 1.0       ┆ 0.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.5       ┆ 0.0       ┆ 1.0 │
└───────────┴───────────┴─────┘
```

As for your current approach - you could `pl.concat_list()`

```
>>> (
...    df
...    .select([
...       pl.col(pl.Int64).cast(pl.Float64), 
...       pl.col(pl.Float64)])
...    .select(
...       pl.concat_list(
...          pl.pearson_corr("a", pl.exclude("a"))
...       )
...    )
... )
shape: (1, 1)
┌──────────────────┐
│ a                │
│ ---              │
│ list[f64]        │
╞══════════════════╡
│ [-0.866025, 0.5] │
└──────────────────┘
```

You can convert it to a struct and `.unnest()` to split it into columns:

```
>>> (
...    df
...    .select([
...       pl.col(pl.Int64).cast(pl.Float64), 
...       pl.col(pl.Float64)])
...    .select(
...       pl.concat_list(
...          pl.pearson_corr("a", pl.exclude("a"))
...       ).arr.to_struct())
...    .unnest("a")
... )
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────┐
│ field_0   ┆ field_1 │
│ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ f64       ┆ f64     │
╞═══════════╪═════════╡
│ -0.866025 ┆ 0.5     │
└───────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: thanks - DataFrame.pearson_corr looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I came up with:

```py
In [52]: numeric = df.select([pl.col(pl.Int64).cast(pl.Float64), pl.col(pl.Float64)])

In [53]: numeric.select([pl.pearson_corr('a', col).alias(f'corr_a_{col}') for col in numeric.columns if col != 'a'])
Out[53]:
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬──────────┐
│ corr_a_d  ┆ corr_a_b │
│ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════╪══════════╡
│ -0.866025 ┆ 0.5      │
└───────────┴──────────┘
```

Is there a way to do this without having to assign to a temporary variable?